# In Java Proxy, if i use an Object's method (like toString()),why it's method.invoke(this),not method.invoke(proxy) or other

Tags: java, proxy

In some code,like Mybatis,I saw the use of JDK-proxy.
Example:
 `org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.ConnectionLogger`:

```
public final class ConnectionLogger extends BaseJdbcLogger implements InvocationHandler {

  @Override
  public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] params)
      throws Throwable {
    try {
      if (Object.class.equals(method.getDeclaringClass())) {
        return method.invoke(this, params);
      }
    }
...
}
}
```

Maybe my code like this :

```
UserMapper user = getProxy(UserMapper.class);
user.hashCode()
```

If i use the method like `hashCode()` , it means i want to get the hashCode from the user, not user's Proxy.hashCode(), not invocationHandler.hashCode().And I really try to change the method like this,it  happens an error:

```
if (Object.class.equals(method.getDeclaringClass())) {
        return method.invoke(proxy, params);
}
```

But why use 'this'(is this means an object from ConnectionLogger ?)
Please tell me ,and sorry for my English ;)

Comment: Because you're invoking a method in the base class. You only got here because someone else did the equivalent of `Method.invoke(proxy, ...)`. If you do that yourself you will recurse infinitely.

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply.Yes,I have known the "recurse infinitely".But I couldn't understand why they use `method.invoke(this,args)`. 'this' is the instance of `ConnectionLogger` (or `InvocationHandler`),not instance of `UserMapper`(like my code above).If I can get the `class` of `UserMapper`,is that much better like `method.invoke(class.newInstance(),args)`? Are they same?

Answer (score 0):

You guessed right. The proxy address refers to the invocationhandler. Here is the test

```
@Override
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {

    if (Object.class.equals(method.getDeclaringClass())) {
        System.out.println(this);
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this)));
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(proxy)));

        return method.invoke(this, args);
    }

    return "ddd";
}
```

```
            public static void main(String[] args) {
    InsertDataHandler c =new InsertDataHandler();
    Object L=c.getProxy();
 //   L.toString();
    System.out.println(L.toString());

}  

        E:\xzb\jdk\bin\java.exe 
         com.example.tenant.InsertDataHandler@728938a9
         728938a9
         21b8d17c
         com.example.tenant.InsertDataHandler@728938a9
```